# Evidence that there's no evidence

Tags: scala, implicit

Is there a `Not[Ev]` type, or a way to implement it, that I can use in the following way

```
def someMethod[X,Y](implicit ev:Not[X <:< Option[Y])= ???
```

Meaning the type X is not an Option[_] type? (and more could be done with that)

Comment: If you use **Shapeless** there is `=! :=`

Comment: But that doesn't allow me to write implicits like `Not[Ordering[X]]` (meaning X cannot be ordered)

Comment: I believe **cats** has that `Not` you want, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 3):

Docs of [`implicitAmbiguous`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/annotation/implicitAmbiguous.html) suggest the following implementation of type inequality

```
trait =!=[C, D]

implicit def neq[E, F] : E =!= F = null

@annotation.implicitAmbiguous("Could not prove ${J} =!= ${J}")
implicit def neqAmbig1[G, H, J] : J =!= J = null
implicit def neqAmbig2[I] : I =!= I = null
```

where

```
def someMethod[X,Y](implicit ev: X =!= Option[Y])= ???

someMethod[Int, String]       // ok
someMethod[Option[Int], Int]  // error
```

Comment: This is very resourceful. Creating making two implicits be eligible so that compiler fails with an ambiguous implicit.